# How to call a function after new WooCommerce product is published manually

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create an extra WooCommerce product whenever a product is being created manually.

This is what i tried:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'on_product_creation', 10, 3);
 function on_product_creation($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
 if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
            
            
         $post_data = array(
            'post_name'     => 'test2',
            'post_title'    => 'test2',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'product',
        );

        $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
        $product = new WC_Product_Subscription( $product_id );
        $product->set_regular_price( 1 );
        $product->set_price( 1 );
        $product->save();   
        $id = $product->get_id();
        update_post_meta($id, "_subscription_length", 12);
        update_post_meta($id, "_subscription_price", 1); 
            
            
            
            
         $log = "productCreated";
         file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
     }

  }
```

For some reason my function doesn't run after I create a product.

I am trying to fire the hook only when the product been created manually to avoid recursion (a product creation will trigger itself) is there
a way to know how the product have been created ?

Answer (score 0):

This hook `woocommerce_process_product_meta`  will run only when the product is manually created/updated. **Tested OK with WC 6.2**

```
/**
 * Save meta box data.
 *
 * @param int     $post_id WP post id.
 * @param WP_Post $post Post object.
 */
function action_woocommerce_process_product_meta($post_id, $post) {
    // make action magic happen here... 


    $product = new WC_Product_Simple();
    $product->set_name('Sample product');
    $product->set_status('publish');
    $product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
    $product->set_price(19.99);
    $product->set_regular_price(19.99);
    $product->set_sold_individually(true);
    $product->save();
}

// add the action 
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'action_woocommerce_process_product_meta', 10, 2);
```

Comment: is it possible to run it, only when product is created?

Comment: also the hook not firing for me, i am using it in a custom plugin

Comment: Add the code into your active theme functions.php file. The code can be made run only for create